# ArangoDb: Time from save() to availability through AQL - waitForSync?

Tags: arangodb

In my NodeJS backed REST API, using the ArangoJS library, I'm calling the `await save(...)` on a document in a collection. *Note* I'm not using using the `waitForSync` option.

Right after the `await` on the save, I'll send a SSE event to the client, which then immediately calls another REST API method, which uses AQL to query the very same collection. Unfortunately I get the previous (old/unchanged) data back. Waiting a sec then AQL-querying gives me the fresh data though.

Is `waitForSync` the solution? Most documentation states that this option waits for data to sync to the disk, but as I understand ArangoDB keep most data in memory, so it shouldn't affect the following query, which should query against memory?

Anyone care to explain?

**Update**

see my own answer

Comment: My expectation would also be that `await` alone should be sufficient. Using `waitForSync` should not be necessary. As you said, the purpose of the latter is to make sure data modifications on the server have been synced to persistent storage. But any modifications should be visible for subsequent callers instantly once a data modification query has returned successfully to the caller. Are you writing to and reading from the same server, or do you have a multi-server setup (in terms of ArangoDB)?

Comment: It's the same server. I'll try to recreate it in a minimal setup. There could be other sources of failure here, such as the Nginx server in front of Nodejs.

Comment: you should move your edit down to an answer and mark the question as answered. That would help others.

Comment: No problem - posted the update as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to mark this as answered:**

As expected, there is nothing wrong with ArangoDb. Thanks to the comment/confirmation that await should be enough, I investigated further around my setup. Found that the problem was with caching, and adding a Cache-Control header with 'no-cache' resolved the issue.

Funny thing is that when developer console was open in Chrome, I never had problems. Found that the checkbox 'disable cache' in development mode had hidden the issue during development. Issue being a lot of 304 Not Changed responses.